# Frame updating variable from main form

Tags: delphi

I have a form `FormOrder` which during run-time is creating dynamically some frames under a `TPageControl` component. Basically each tab from `PageControl` have inside the frame called `FrameCust`.

```
uses ..., UnitFrameSupp;

TPageSupp = record
    SuppId: Cardinal;
    SuppName: String;
    TabSheet: TTabSheet;
    Frame: TFrameSupp;
  end;

  TOrder = record
    Id: Cardinal;
    RefYear: Word;
    RefNo: Cardinal;
    Loaded: Boolean;
    Changed: Boolean;
    PageCust: TPageCust;
    PageSupp: array of TPageSupp;
  end;

TFormOrder = class(TForm)
  private
    FOrder: TOrder;
    procedure SetOrderId(const Value: Cardinal);
  public
    property OrderId: Cardinal write SetOrderId;
  end;
```

...

```
TFrameSupp = class(TFrame)
    BtnSave: TBitBtn;
    procedure BtnSavelick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSuppId: Cardinal;
    FSuppName: String;
    FOrderId: Cardinal;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property SuppId: Cardinal write FSuppId;
    property SuppName: String write FSuppName;
    property OrderId: Cardinal write FOrderId;
  end;

procedure TFrameSupp.BtnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOrderId:= 100;

  //here I would like to update the value of `Order.Id` from `FormOrder`
  //and also to inform the others frames about this change.
end;
```

How can I update the value of `Order.Id` from main form and to inform the others frames about this change?

I know that I can make `Order:TOrder` public under a `DataModule` and to access it from all units without to create circular reference.

There is a better way?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. You're very tight to UI in your design and if your application will grow, consider implementing design patterns like e.g. MVP. That will isolate UI from data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would use MainForm to update all the frames, so the problem reduces to informing the main form of the change.

There are (at least) two ways to do this. One is to include a uses clause to the **implementation** part of the frame definition, and then either use (Owner as TFormOrder) or access the form directly.

The other, and in my view better, approach is to create a callback property, probably on a common ancestor of all the frames, just as you would create an Event on a component, e.g.

```
property OnIDChange : TNotifyEvent read fOnIDChange write fOnIDChange;
```

then in ButonSaveClick add the block

```
if assigned( fOnIDChange ) then fOnIDChange( self );
```

You could improve this by defining your own Event type like this

```
TOnIDChange = procedure( Sender : TObject; NewVal : cardinal ) of object;
```

Then

```
property OnIDChange : TOnIDChange read fOnIDChange write fOnIDChange;
```

then in ButonSaveClick add the block

```
if assigned( fOnIDChange ) then fOnIDChange( self, fOrderID );
```

The downside of this approach is the you have to define the event procedure in the main form and assign it to the frames on creation.

Comment: I choose the second way. Thanks!